# AS3: Cannot type in an input TextField with an embedded pixel font

Tags: actionscript-3, embed, pixel-fonts

In order to use a pixel font in my textfields, I have created a font class in the Flash IDE. Then, I created a TextField instance with the font embedded with the anti aliasing set to bitmap. I export an SWC with all those things.

I created a class with a nice API to be able to deal with this stuff easily.

In FDT, I use class and this all works properly.

The issue here is that I now want to use one of these textfields as an input. I tried setting the textfield type to TextFieldType.INPUT, however the only thing that this does is allow me to select the text, I cannot type. I also created another asset with the type already set to input, does not work either.

I tried with just the asset, not with my class, and then I can type ok.

Is there something that prevents a textfield from being editable once it is part of a sprite? Here is the code of my class with the API:

```
package net.jansensan.as3fflikeui.text
{
    // + ----------------------------------------
    //      [ IMPORTS ]
    // + ----------------------------------------

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.StyleSheet;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldType;

    /**
    * @author Mat Janson Blanchet
    */
    public class BitmapTextfield extends Sprite
    {
        // + ----------------------------------------
        //      [ CONSTANTS ]
        // + ----------------------------------------

        [Embed(source="../assets/css/ui.css", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
        private const   CSS :Class;


        // + ----------------------------------------
        //      [ VARIABLES ]
        // + ----------------------------------------

        // display objects
        private var _textfieldAsset :MovieClip;
        private var _textfield      :TextField;
        private var _shadow         :BitmapTextfieldAsset;

        // private / protected
        private var _styleSheet :StyleSheet;


        // + ----------------------------------------
        //      [CONSTRUCTOR ]
        // + ----------------------------------------

        public function BitmapTextfield(type:String = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC)
        {
            switch(type)
            {
                case TextFieldType.DYNAMIC:
                    _textfieldAsset = new BitmapTextfieldAsset();
                    _textfield = _textfieldAsset.textfieldTXT;
                    _textfield.selectable = false;
                    break;

                case TextFieldType.INPUT:
                    _textfieldAsset = new BitmapInputTextfieldAsset();
                    _textfield = _textfieldAsset.textfieldTXT;
                    _textfield.selectable = true;
                    break;
            }
            _textfield.htmlText = "";

            _shadow = new BitmapTextfieldAsset();
            _shadow.textfieldTXT.htmlText = "";
            _shadow.x = 1;
            _shadow.y = 1;

            _styleSheet = new StyleSheet();
            _styleSheet.parseCSS(new CSS());
            setStyle(_styleSheet);

            addChild(_shadow);
            addChild(_textfieldAsset);
        }


        // + ----------------------------------------
        //      [ PUBLIC METHODS ]
        // + ----------------------------------------

        public function setWidth(newWidth:int):void
        {
            _textfield.width = newWidth;
            _shadow.textfieldTXT.width = newWidth;
        }


        public function setHeight(newHeight:int):void
        {
            _textfield.height = newHeight;
            _shadow.textfieldTXT.height = newHeight;
        }


        public function setStyle(newStyle:StyleSheet):void
        {
            _styleSheet = newStyle;
            _textfield.styleSheet = _styleSheet;
        }


        public function setText(newText:String):void
        {
            _textfield.htmlText = newText;
            _shadow.textfieldTXT.htmlText = newText;
        }


        public function getText():String
        {
            return _textfield.text;
        }


        public function getHTMLText():String
        {
            return _textfield.htmlText;
        }


        public function getTextNumLines():uint
        {
            return _textfield.numLines;
        }


    }
}
```

Any guidance would be useful, thanks in advance!

-mat.

Comment: Does it work as expected with a non-embedded font?

Answer (score 2):

A text field with a style sheet is not editable. In other words, a text field with the type property set to `TextFieldType.INPUT` applies the `StyleSheet` to the default text for the text field, but the content will no longer be editable by the user. Consider using the `TextFormat` class to assign styles to input text fields.